# Pip Install python package: cannot find requirements.txt

Tags: python, path, pip, command, requirements

I am trying to install the package gamry-parser (https://pypi.org/project/gamry-parser/).

However, the command window is unable to find the requirements.txt in the location it is looking for. I have tried to search the path it is searching in my computer, but it does not seem to exist(*c:\users\name\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-rfy1sh\gamry-parser\setup.py*). In addition, the requirements.txt does in fact exist, but not in this nonexistant path. I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the packaging of this project has issues, it would make sense to report the issue to the maintainers of that project.

Answer (score 1):

`gamry-parser` 0.4.1 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/gamry-parser/0.4.1/#files) a wheel for Python 3 and a source dist that will be used for Python 2.7. I tested them — the wheel installed with Python 3.7, no problem.

The problem is with Python 2.7 and the source distribution — the sdist lacks `requirements.txt`. To fix it they need to add file [`MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute):

```
echo include requirements.txt > MANIFEST.in
git add MANIFEST.in
git commit -m "Add MANIFEST.in for sdist"
```

Please [report the issue](https://github.com/bcliang/gamry-parser/issues) or send a pull request.